# hpdf not found by LuaHPDF MakeFile (but I've already installed it)

Tags: pdf, lua, libharu

Executing the MakeFile of LuaHPDF ([this one](https://github.com/jung-kurt/luahpdf/blob/master/Makefile)), it complains that `#include <hpdf.h>` directive has failed. I've installed it (v. 2.3.0) using `apt` . Despite of a hpdf.so taking place in the system, no header (hpdf.h) was added. This means such installation wasn't have effect.

I'm working with Debian 11 and lua 5.4.

How to install hpdf in my computer in order to such header being reachable to `gcc`? Should I create one by my self? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian, you must also install the [`libhpdf-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libhpdf-dev) package to get the *development files* (headers) necessary to compile [LuaHPDF](https://github.com/jung-kurt/luahpdf/tree/master) (and then link against [`libhpdf-2.3.0.so`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libhpdf-2.3.0)).

This is a general pattern when compiling from source.

Note that this will only solve an initial problem, as LuaHPDF targets Lua 5.2, and will not compile under Lua 5.4, as there have been breaking changes (very common between Lua versions).

You'll either need to compile and link against Lua 5.2, or port the source to Lua 5.4.

That said, the only issue I ran into when compiling is that Lua 5.4 dropped the `LUA_QS` and `LUA_QL` macros from [*luaconf.h*](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/luaconf.h.html#LUA_QS) (present most recently in Lua 5.3 [for compatibility](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html#LUA_QS)). Adding them back near the top of [*hpdf.c*](https://github.com/jung-kurt/luahpdf/blob/master/hpdf.c)

```
#define LUA_QL(x)       "'" x "'"
#define LUA_QS          LUA_QL("%s")
```

does get this to compile cleanly, though I cannot comment on the stability of the library with this basic patch.

---

<sup>For complete transparency, I tested this on [Solus](https://getsol.us/), where [*libHaru*](http://libharu.org/) is available as [`libharu`](https://solus.pkgs.org/rolling/solus-shannon-x86_64/libharu-2.3.0-1-1-x86_64.eopkg.html) and [`libharu-devel`](https://solus.pkgs.org/rolling/solus-shannon-x86_64/libharu-devel-2.3.0-1-1-x86_64.eopkg.html). The *process* should be the same on Debian, even if the names are different - I just don't have a Debian machine on hand.</sup>

Comment: See also https://github.com/lhf/lhpdf-fix

Comment: Nice! You give a better panorama about how the whole thing works. But now, complains that no lauxlib.h wasn't found. I've tried to resolve this, in some way, analogously to your answer but with no success. Do you have some suggestion?  NOTE: executing lhpdf-fix the same issue was triggered.

Comment: Same idea, `<lauxlib.h>` is the header file describing Lua's auxiliary library. Install one of `libluaX.Y-dev` (e.g., [`liblua5.3-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/liblua5.3-dev)) to make sure its on your system. Note that the makefile [for *LuaHPF*](https://github.com/jung-kurt/luahpdf/blob/master/Makefile#L7) looks specifically for Lua 5.2, whereas the makefile [for *lhpdf-fix*](https://github.com/lhf/lhpdf-fix/blob/main/Makefile#L6) looks specifically for Lua 5.4. Edit these paths where appropriate so that the compiler can find the correct files.

Comment: Finally! Running LuaHPDF! Following this guide I could resolve other issues. In gerenal, installing via apt lacing libraries following the example form: -lpng  error-> libpng-dev.

The suffix "-dev" was the great new to me!

Thank you for your decisive help!